# Execute HTTP request to an external server when any CouchDB Data changes

Tags: python, asp.net, oauth, couchdb, httprequest

I am fairly new in CouchDB but successfully performed create, update, delete data using Fauxton UI. I have some PouchDB clients which will directly sync with this CouchDB database using HTTP Protocol. This PouchDB client will be authenticated with another ASP.NET Identity server and send a Bearer Token with  each of its call to the CouchDB server.

I have a remote Windows server (exposed with ASP.NET Web API endpoints) which has implementation of Permission Management (using ASP.NET Identity) and also another server which has ElasticSearch database (for fastest searching) instance.

**My problem is, I want to execute some functions (using JavaScript, Python or any other supported language) to check the permission with that ASP.NET remote server and if permitted, then proceed the call to the CouchDB. 
I also want to capture the `_changes` event of CouchDB and execute another HTTP call to my ElasticSearch instance to insert/update this change.**

I have seen, I can write Python/Ruby code to which can execute a HTTP call. But I failed to understand how to hook these functions with my CouchDB (instance/cluster) so that these functions could be called and executed.

Answer (score 0):

Two JS modules that could solve parts of your issues:

- [follow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow), to execute a function everytime a change happen on the followed CouchDB database
- [couch2elastic4sync](https://github.com/ryanramage/couch2elastic4sync), uses the follow module to keep a CouchDB database and a ElasticSearch index in sync

Comment: How about requesting for the ASP.NET Server for the Authentication? Can you please give me something on this please?

Comment: I have zero knowledge on anything ASP.NET sorry

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is, how can I authenticate with some external server by sending the request token? since I want to use Bearer Token, that means ASP.NET is not an issue here. I just want to identify the point where I need to write the code in CouchDB instance.

Answer (score 0):

*For the authentication problem*, your best approach is to use a proxy server in front of your CouchDB instance which can authenticate the Bearer token sent with the PouchDB requests using the ASP.NET Identity server before forwarding them onto CouchDB. It sounds like you may have to write this yourself; I'm not familiar with the ASP.NET solution but I don't think CouchDB supports what you'll need to do itself.

*To get changes from CouchDB into your ElasticSearch instance*, you could try the answer from @maxlath or try https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-river-couchdb which I've seen work successfully in the past.